# How to run separate threads in pygtk

Tags: python, multithreading, textview, gtk, pygtk

I have a pygtk application which runs as soon as my python script is opened. Along with gtk.main() I have a thread which is started at the beginning of the script, which refreshes a gtk.TextView() instance:

```
def listen(self):
    while True:
        print "refreshing"
        data = self.socket.recv(buffer_size)
        if data:
            self.txtBuffer.insert(self.txtBuffer.get_end_iter(), data + "\n")
            print data

thread.start_new_thread(self.listen, ())
self.set_up_gui() # gtk.main()
```

However, when I run the program, the gui opens, but no "refreshing" text is printed, nor is any data printed when sent to the socket. I have attempted to use glib.add_idle() to thread this program, however that only runs the separate thread when the gui is idle (which is infrequent). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the text buffer from a different thread without any synchronization, which is unsupported. To fix that, replace `self.txtBuffer.insert(...)` with `gobject.idle_add(lambda: self.txtBuffer.insert(...))`. That tells the GUI thread to update the text buffer at the next main loop iteration, which is guaranteed to work without explicit synchronization.

You should make sure that the GUI thread  is not blocked, i.e. that it's running `gtk.main()` and only processing GUI updates such as the above `textBuffer.insert`. Long-running/blocking tasks should be delegated to other threads or processes, as your code already tries to do. When this is implemented, GUI updates will appear to happen instantaneously.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16949065/1600898) for additional details on PyGTK and threading.

Comment: The GUI runs perfectly, however, the data is still not being refreshed. The data isn't received either, because nothing is being printed by print data

Edit: It seems to me that the GUI simply doesn't allow the thread to run at all

Comment: Fixed it, just had to implement your solution correctly, thanks a lot!